# How to validate email, password and confirm password?

Tags: php, mysql

[Code of save.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnAuc.png)

[Code of the sign up form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lY0cS.png)

the codes are ok and i want to put some validation that says "Email has already been registered" and "your password doesnt match"
this is the whole code for the sign up

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Index</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
  <script src="bootstrap/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 
 </head>
 <body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" style="border-radius:0px 0px 0px 0px;">
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     </button>
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">JMK Sounds & Light</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
       <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Equipments <span class="caret"></span></a>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="soundsys.php">Sound System</a></li>
        <li><a href="lights.php">Lights</a></li>
       </ul>
       <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
       <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
      </li>
     </ul>
     
     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse pull-right" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="dropdown">
       <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Sign in | Sign up <span class="caret" ></span></a>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="padding:5px;">
           <li>
            <div class="form-group">
             <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Username" style="margin-bottom:5px;" required/>
          <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Password" style="margin-bottom:5px;" required/>
          <center><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Sign in</button></center>
         </div>
           </li>
              <center><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signup">Sign Up</button></center>
         <li>
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" action="header.php" method="post">
          </form>
         </li>
       </ul>
      </li>
     </ul>
     </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </nav>
  
  <div class="modal fade" id="signup" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true"> &times; </span></button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Sign Up</h4>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
      <form action="save.php" method="post">     
       <div class="form-group">
          
        <input type="text" name="fname" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="First Name" required/><br />
        <input type="text" name="sname" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Last Name" required/><br />
        <center>
         <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" required> Male &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
         <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" required> Female<br /><br />
        </center>
        <input type="text" name="address" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Address" required/><br />
        <input type="text" name="contact" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="+639" required/><br />
        <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Email" required/><br />
        <input type="text" name="uname" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Username" required/><br />
        <input type="password" name="pword" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Password" required/><br />
        <input type="password" name="cpword" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Confirm Password" required/><br />
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Submit</button>
     

       </div>
      </form>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For this type of validation you can use php
here is a sample validation you can check and modify:

```
if ( isset($_POST['submit']) ) {

    // clean user inputs to prevent sql injections
    $name = trim($_POST['name']);
    $name = strip_tags($name);
    $name = htmlspecialchars($name);

    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $email = strip_tags($email);
    $email = htmlspecialchars($email);

    $pass = trim($_POST['pass']);
    $pass = strip_tags($pass);
    $pass = htmlspecialchars($pass);

    // basic name validation
    if (empty($name)) {
        $error = true;
        $nameError = "Please enter your full name.";
    } else if (strlen($name) < 3) {
        $error = true;
        $nameError = "Name must have atleat 3 characters.";
    } else if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/",$name)) {
        $error = true;
        $nameError = "Name must contain alphabets and space.";
    }

    //basic email validation
    if ( !filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {
        $error = true;
        $emailError = "Please enter valid email address.";
    } else {
        // check email exist or not
        $query = "SELECT userEmail FROM yourtable WHERE userEmail='$email'";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if($count!=0){
            $error = true;
            $emailError = "Provided Email is already in use.";
        }
    }
    // password validation
    if (empty($pass)){
        $error = true;
        $passError = "Please enter password.";
    } else if(strlen($pass) < 6) {
        $error = true;
        $passError = "Password must have atleast 6 characters.";
    }

    // password encrypt using SHA256();
    $password = hash('sha256', $pass);
    }
```

Comment: sir... can you explain this in a simple way?? xD sorry cause im just a beginner in php and SQL :( huhuhuhuhu

Comment: trim, strip_tags, htmlspecialchars are used to pevent sql injections, you can search the internet for details.Next is pattern matching preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/",$name) here for this patterrn only spaces and alphabets are allowed. filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) is used for validating email for ex ur email must contain @ and a dot.Next it will check from database weather the provided email is present there or not.Next hash('sha256', $pass) encrypt the pass for sequrity. Thanks please upvote.

Comment: Thanks sir :D ok ill upvote thanks for the samples hehe

Comment: This is really not good advice, and the answer ideally should be deleted. Your database library is deprecated in 5.6+ and removed from 7.0+. Additionally you should be using parameter binding rather than attempting to filter user input manually. cc @ErickChoi.

Comment: oh sorry sir i just cant understand xD im soooooo noob in PHP SQL T_T

Comment: @ErickChoi: Chiaro's answer is safer, but that leaves you more work to do. However do remember that it is not safe to copy and paste code without understanding it, and volunteers cannot be expected to do all your work for you. Have you tried some (good) tutorials to get used to these kinds of problems?

Answer (score 1):

Well, doing that is actually quite simple.

You just need to attempt to connect to the database and in your SQL, search the table using the email provided. I have used the PDO extension in the following code.

Example:

```
function Search_Customer($email)
{
    global $db;
    $query = "
        SELECT customerID, CONCAT (firstName,' ', lastName) AS fullName,
        city 
        FROM customers
        WHERE email = :email";

    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindValue(':email', $email);
    $statement->execute();
    $customer = $statement->fetchAll();
    $statement->closeCursor();

    return $customer;
}
```

And then when you call the method, you check if the value returned is null ("Email does not exist") or there is a customer returned ("Emails exists").

Of course there is the password that is involved too but the same principle also applies there.

You can then display the response message by means of a simple "echo" / "print" or a more complicated JavaScript code